# Read a different column BELOW another column

Tags: r

I'm using some exotic software to analyze some of my results, and it decides to output data in this fashion

```
Dem-Dexc   Aem-Dexc   Aem-Aexc      S         E      
3380.4193   581.2386    -141.1475   1.0369  0.1467
3236.4193   1608.2386   570.8525    0.8946  0.3320
1057.4193   557.2386    4533.8525   0.2626  0.3451
3098.4193   4928.2386   1524.8525   0.8404  0.6140
3716.4193   2427.2386   6633.8525   0.4808  0.3951   


   Fit   
0.4693
0.4693
0.4693
0.4693
0.4693
```

How can I read the `Fit` column along with the rest?

Comment: You could do two `read.csv` functions, the first with an `nrow` argument, and the second with a `skip` argument.

Comment: Is it tab-delimited? Why not `read.csv("file", sep="\t", header=T)`?

Comment: @lmo Didn't think of that! Ended up reading it twice, second time skipping the first 700 rows (in the original data) and `cbind`ing it to the first afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured I'd post it as a full answer (thanks to lmo)

Full data can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/HrBSVCZP

```
library(readr)

Top <- read_delim("~/Desktop/File.txt", 
                    "\t",
                    escape_double = FALSE,
                    col_names = FALSE, # Need to get rid of the weird multi-whitespace separation
                    trim_ws = TRUE,
                    skip = 6)

Top <- na.omit(Top) # Removes bottom column entirely because of adjacent NA rows

Btm <- read_delim("~/Desktop/File.txt", 
                    "\t", escape_double = FALSE, 
                    col_names = TRUE, 
                    trim_ws = TRUE, 
                    skip = 708)

df <- cbind(Top, Btm)
```

The first columns need to be properly renamed, as I had to skip that earlier.